# How to get a integer value about Arraylist index

Tags: java, android, arraylist, indexing

How to get a integer value for arraylist item index ,if you click arraylist fifth number then the integer value `a=5`
How can i do this?

```
ArrayList a;
al = new ArrayList();

for(int i = 0; i < linksArray.length(); ++i) {
    a.add(linksArray.getJSONObject(i).get("fullText"));
}
```

I added my json values in "a"

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.activity_listview_2, a);
listviewMakale.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and then I have listview click function and i want to if click fifth element 
`int indexItem = 5;` I don't want to with listview click listener position value, I want to arraylist index.

all activity code,the main problem is if users search anything in edittext

```
  ListView listviewMakale;
    ArrayList a22 = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList al;
  private  ArrayAdapter adapter;
 private  EditText ara;

    String url = "myurl";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.makale);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        listviewMakale = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listviewMakale);


        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String string) {
                parseJsonData(string);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hata-Tekrar Deneyiniz!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

  StringRequest request2 = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String string) {
                parseJsonDataLinks(string);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hata-Tekrar Deneyiniz!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        //baslık için
        RequestQueue rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(makale.this);
        rQueue.add(request);

        //linkler için
        RequestQueue rQueue2 = Volley.newRequestQueue(makale.this);
        rQueue2.add(request2);



    }


    void parseJsonData(String jsonString) {
        try {
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            JSONArray linksArray = object.getJSONArray("makale");
                 al = new ArrayList();

            for(int i = 0; i < linksArray.length(); ++i) {
                al.add(linksArray.getJSONObject(i).get("fullText"));
            }

            adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.activity_listview_2, al);
            listviewMakale.setAdapter(adapter);

            EditText ara=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.ara);


            listviewMakale.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {



                    final   String linkler="url"+a22.get(position);

                    Toast.makeText(makale.this,String.valueOf(al.indexOf(position)),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(makale.this);
                    builder.setTitle("Makale");
                    builder.setMessage("");
                    builder.setNegativeButton("İPTAL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {


                        }
                    });

                    builder.setPositiveButton("TAMAM", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(linkler), "text/html");
                            startActivity(intent);

                        }
                    });


                    builder.show();
                    }
            });

            ara.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                makale.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(charSequence);
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                }
            });

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    //linklere erişiyoruz
        void parseJsonDataLinks (String jsonString2) {
            try {
                JSONObject object2 = new JSONObject(jsonString2);
                JSONArray linksArray2 = object2.getJSONArray("makale");


                for(int j = 0; j < linksArray2.length(); ++j) {
                    a22.add(linksArray2.getJSONObject(j).get("link"));
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }

}
```

Comment: You mean you want to get your clicked row value? Like if you clicked 5th position in `ListView` then you need data of that position from your `ArrayList`?

Comment: Exactly.I want this

Comment: share your on click code of listView.

Comment: ListView's onItemClickListener has position as parameter, it is exactly same as the index of the underline array of ArrayAdapter.

Comment: onItemClick provides you the position of the clicked Item in it's arguments. Just add Log.d("This is the clicked position   " + position) to the onItemClick method

Comment: I don't want to use listview position value, i need arraylist index value

Comment: As per your above code, Your `ArrayList` index value will be same as your `ListView`click position. You have `ArrayList` of `String` values in above code. What index will be inside `firstArrayListIndex`? What value will be in `myotherarraylist.get(firstArrayListIndex)`?

Comment: i shared my all activity code, the main problem is if users search anything in edittext

Comment: Oh Okay, So you are getting problem when use search and list is getting refreshed. :D

Comment: yes man , when use search second arraylist returns first element,second element etc. actually user searched fiftieth elements :)

Answer (score 0):

you can get item you want from directly adapter like this:

```
adapter.getItem(position)
```

position is index of item.

Answer (score 0):

You can get clicked position on `ListView` `OnItemClickListener`. And that position will be your `ArrayList` position. You can easily retrieve value for that position from `ArrayList`.

```
your_list_view.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long l) {
        String full_text = adapterView.getAdapter().getItem(pos);
        Log.w("Clicked Row", "Data on position " +  pos + " is " + full_text);
    }
});
```

You can also use 
`String full_text = your_array_list.get(pos);` in place of `String full_text = adapterView.getAdapter().getItem(pos);`. Both will return you same value.

Answer (score 0):

Once you will bind the `ArrayList` with `ListView` then it will not change their position until you refresh or reload it.

So you can get values from `ArrayList` by its clicked position of `ListView`.

You can do like.

```
arrayList.get(index);
```

It will return object whatever you passed.